# Use a chart image within a UserForm without saving to disk

Tags: excel, vba, image, userform

Is it possible to use an image within a UserForm without first saving to the disk? Saving to the disk dramatically increases code execution time and creates a mess that I'd have to clean up.

Edit:
Here is a sample project hosted on my Google Drive:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=11bko1qPI30DuN0_MtMRAmhmYYpu6lBb4

This sample should open a UserForm window allowing you to:

1. choose a Sheet (for demo data)
2. generate some random numbers in cells
3. create images from those cells
4. save them to disk and load them in the userform

---

```
' ------------------------------------------------------
' Name: multiImageTest
' Kind: Form
' Purpose: Test the time spent updating images on a UserForm
' Author: Dave
' Date: 1/18/2019
' ------------------------------------------------------

Option Explicit

Private testSheet As Worksheet
Private images As Collection
Private tempImagePath As String

' ----------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure Name: createImg
' Purpose: Create the image control on the UserForm
' Procedure Kind: Function
' Procedure Access: Private
' Parameter image (Long): Used to name the control
' Return Type: image
' Author: Dave
' Date: 1/18/2019
' ----------------------------------------------------------------
Private Function createImg(ByVal image As Long) As MSForms.image
    ' The Id the image will use
    Dim imgId As String: imgId = "img" + CStr(image)

    ' Create the image on the UserForm
    Set createImg = Me.Controls.add("Forms.Image.1", imgId)
    With createImg
        .top = 0
        .left = ((image - 1) * 100) + 10
        .width = 100
        .height = 40
        .PictureAlignment = fmPictureAlignmentTopLeft
        .PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeZoom
        .PictureTiling = False
        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
        .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
        .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
        .BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' black
        .BorderColor = RGB(240, 240, 240) ' almost white
    End With

    ' Create the load time label on the UserForm
    Dim lblLoadTime As MSForms.label
    Set lblLoadTime = Me.Controls.add("Forms.Label.1", imgId + "_loadTime")
    With lblLoadTime
        .top = 40
        .left = ((image - 1) * 100) + 10
        .width = 100
        .height = 15
        .caption = "..."
        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
        .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
        .BorderColor = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' almost white
    End With
End Function

' ----------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure Name: btnGo_Click
' Purpose: Start execution
' Procedure Kind: Sub
' Procedure Access: Private
' Author: Dave
' Date: 1/18/2019
' ----------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub btnGo_Click()
    Set testSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.cbSheetChoice.value)
    Dim area As range: Set area = testSheet.range("A1:C3")

    ' Put some random numbers in each cell
    execute area

End Sub

' ----------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure Name: execute
' Purpose: Do the stuff
' Procedure Kind: Sub
' Procedure Access: Private
' Parameter area (range): The area to take an image
' Author: Dave
' Date: 1/18/2019
' ----------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub execute(ByRef area As range)
    Dim startTime As Double
    Dim secondsElapsed As Double
    Dim tmpImage As MSForms.image
    Dim lblLoadTime As Control
    Dim image As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim column As Long

    ' Fill in the cells with some numbers
    For image = 1 To 5
        For row = 1 To 3
            For column = 1 To 3
                ' So Rnd gives us a random number each time
                Randomize

                area.Cells(row, column).value = Rnd(10)
            Next column
        Next row

        'Remember time
        startTime = Timer

        ' Creat the image and load Time Label
        Set tmpImage = createImg(image)
        Set lblLoadTime = Me.Controls.item("img" + CStr(image) + "_loadTime")

        ' Set the picture path on the userform object
        tmpImage.Picture = LoadPicture(getFile(area, image))

        ' Add to collection
        images.add tmpImage

        ' Set the load time amount
        lblLoadTime.caption = CStr(Round(Timer - startTime, 5)) + "s"
    Next image
End Sub

' ----------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure Name: getFile
' Purpose: Get the File path of the newly generated image
' Procedure Kind: Function
' Procedure Access: Private
' Parameter area (range): The area to create an image from
' Parameter image (Long): Used to name the file
' Return Type: String
' Author: Dave
' Date: 1/18/2019
' ----------------------------------------------------------------
Private Function getFile(ByRef area As range, ByVal image As Long) As String
    Dim fileName As String: fileName = "tempImg" + CStr(image) + ".jpg"

    ' Copy the image to the clipboard
    area.CopyPicture xlPrinter, xlPicture

    With testSheet
        .activate

        ' Create the chart object
        Dim chtObj As ChartObject
        Set chtObj = .ChartObjects.add(image * 150, 0, area.width, area.height)

        ' Name it for easy reference
        chtObj.name = fileName

        ' Resize obj to picture size (otherwise it will be skewed)
        chtObj.width = area.width
        chtObj.height = area.height

        ' Activate the chart so we can work with it, then paste the copied range
        .ChartObjects(fileName).activate

        ActiveChart.Paste

        ' Export the file
        ActiveChart.Export fileName:=tempImagePath + fileName

        ' Delete the temporary chart object
        chtObj.delete
    End With

    getFile = tempImagePath + fileName
End Function

' ----------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure Name: UserForm_Initialize
' Purpose: Init the UserForm
' Procedure Kind: Constructor (Initialize)
' Procedure Access: Private
' Author: Dave
' Date: 1/18/2019
' ----------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' Add each Worksheet name to the dropdown box
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Me.cbSheetChoice.AddItem ws.name
    Next ws

    ' Set the default dropdown choice to the first Sheet
    Me.cbSheetChoice.ListIndex = 0

    ' Init the images collection
    Set images = New Collection

    ' Set the temporary image path
    tempImagePath = application.ActiveWorkbook.path + application.PathSeparator
    Me.lblTempImagePath.caption = tempImagePath
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that's the only way to do. How *dramatically* can it be? A less than 1MB GIF (which a chart should end up in) should save in a fraction of a second. You should post a [mcve] and tell how long it takes to save to the disk.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, I've updated the post with an example.

Comment: `ActiveChart.Export Filename:="C:\Temp\test.png", FilterName:="PNG"` for me takes less than a second to export the chart. By the way you should set the ` FilterName:="PNG"` and use PNG instead of JPEG.

Comment: Maybe I'm not up to date, but AFAIK `.LoadPicture` doesn't support PNGs :-)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ even less than a second is too long. :( On average it takes .25 of a second with a SSD to save each of the files. 20 files = 5 seconds. That's a lot of time.